# Iteratively filtering pandas rows based on different inputs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter out a pandas data-frame based on some a variable list `task_ids` that exist in the df.

for example if `task_ids = [1,5,7]` then I'd want the following functionality:

```
df[(df.task_id = 1) & (df.task_id = 5) & (df.task_id = 7)]
```

How am I able to filter it out using a variable list? e.g. `task_ids` might be a list of size 1 or a list of size 13.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep row with task_id in task_ids:

```
task_ids = [1,5,7]
df[df['task_id'].isin(task_ids)]
```

another way:

```
df.loc[(df['task_id'] == 1) | (df['task_id'] == 5) | (df['task_id'] == 7)]
```